# Inserting a New Cell Into A UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I’m trying to add in a new cell into my collection view, only if it has more than one item already in it. I have no worked much with collection views, and research in the docs and this site had not helped solve this issue yet. So, on my cellForItemAtIndexPath method, I do a check to see if it is populated. If not, I add the cell, like so:

```
    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.myArray.count != 0) {
        return self.myArray.count + 1;
    }
    else {
        return self.myArray.count;
    }
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyNormalCollectionViewCellS *cells = (MyNormalCollectionViewCells *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyNormalCollectionViewCells” forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
    DataClass *data = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cells configureMyNormalCellsWith:data];

    if (0 < self.myArray.count) {

        UICollectionViewCell *deleteCell = [UICollectionViewCell new];
        deleteCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        NSArray *newData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:deleteCell, nil];

        [self.myArray addObjectsFromArray:newData];

        NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.myCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths];

        return deleteCell;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

For some reason, I have an assertion being thrown, stating:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an
>   existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of
>   items contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus
>   the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Of course, the number usually varies, but it's always angry about that extra cell. Everything is fine up until I try and add it in. Now, being unfamiliar with collection views and after browsing related questions upon this site, I decided it was time to ask the pros.

Does anyone know how I should change this code in order to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify data source in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. Return different number of items in `- collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` instead:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.dataArray.count > 0) { 
        return self.dataArray.count + 1; 
    }
    else { 
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

In `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` you should return your "normal" cell for "normal" item, and "extra" cell for that extra one, depending on the value of `indexPath.row`. For example:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row < self.dataArray.count) { // if indexPath.row is within data array bounds
         // dequeue, setup and return "normal" cell
    } else { // this is your "+1" cell
        // dequeue, setup and return "extra" cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this solution, but I run into the error '  NSRangeException', reason:  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5] '

Comment: are you trying to `self.dataArray[indexPath.row]` in `else` block of `(indexPath.row < self.data.count)`?

Comment: Or how can I change my code to have this happen? Thought I understood you correctly but must not have...

Comment: Don't modify data source in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. Don't `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that now. Since I'm still a bit new to Objective-C, would you mind showing how that should look in your OP? Thank you again for all of your help Kreiri, hopefully this answer helps many others as well! :)