# Add individual cell to UiCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm attempting to create a custom cell at the end of my `UICollectionViewCell`. The last item should be an "custom cell" so the user can add another record. Tried some solutions but without success. My code so far seems like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! EquipamentosCollectionViewCell
        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {
            cell.imgEquip?.image = UIImage(named: "novavisita")
            return cell
        }else{
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            return cell
        }
}
```

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146462/adding-a-static-cell-to-a-uicollectionview), but it`s not how I want it to work.

The problem is that it's replacing the first.

Any suggestions of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then add that cell at last:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! EquipamentosCollectionViewCell
    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).item == YOUR_COLLECTION.count - 1{
        //Add New Record Cell
        cell.imgEquip?.image = UIImage(named: "novavisita")
        return cell
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I add a new cell instead of just "replacing"the configuration of an existing cell?? (I'm kind of new in iOS development)

Comment: You have another routine numberOfItemsInSection in which you tell the collection view how many items in the view.  Have it return YOUR_COLLECTION.count + 1.

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro http://stackoverflow.com/a/31546100/1208191
You need to read this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started